G-code for stationary extrusion
I have this electro-magnetic droplet (EMD) printhead from Cellink that allows for extruding droplets. I would like to extrude droplets at specific coordinates while the printhead is stationary, preferably for X amount of seconds. However, I cannot find a G-code command that allows this, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Hi Rishi, and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Do you need to activate and deactivate the elctro-magnet each time to get a droplet, or is it "fire-and-forget", meaning it it is activated it starts dripping?

Thank you for your comment 0scar. The electro-magnetic droplet (EMD) printhead basically functions as a normal printhead. So if you have a g-code that says 'G1 X1 Y1 E1' (for example), the printhead will move to that coordinate while extruding droplets. On the 3D (bio)printer interface, you can set the frequency and duration in which the droplets are extruded.

OK, then use G4 [P<time(ms)>] [S<time(sec)>] to stay a predefined amount of time at that spot. Does that answer the question? It can then be made an answer as answering in comments is not allowed.

I find it strange that the "droplet extruder" can be addressed by the E parameter. But this could well be handled by a piece of firmware running on this special extruder. I wonder what the difference between a E1 and an E10 is? With electromagnetic switches you'd expect using an M code instead, like M42.

Using G4 would not do it, because that command simply puts the printhead stationary without it extruding at that position. I want the printhead to be stationary at a specific coordinate, and extrude while it is stationary at that coordinate.

So your droplet extruder is just a simple thing, I hoped it had a PCB that received input from the G-code to instruct a dripping pattern. If that was true, the G4 would do the trick. My last question, G-code is not real-time, due to acceleration and deceleration you would not obtain precize time from the feed rate. How is this droplet extruder supposed to work? Does it normally have a different firmware? To make a drop you need to activate and de-activate the magnet? Is it one drop on the location, or is it dripping at one loacation? Please update the question with more information.

I figured it out!
Their firmware apparently has a M750 command in which you can set the pressure of the printhead for x amount of microseconds. So I can simply use the G0 command to move the printhead to a specific coordinate, and then the M750 command to extrude for x ms at that coordinate while it remains stationary.
I don't know if this command is applicable across all 3D printers, but it can be used for Cellink bioprinters.
Additionally, to answer 0scar's question regarding how the EMD printhead is able to extrude droplets: through the printing interface (and g-code commands M2065 and M2067), the open time and cycle time can be set. These times are in the microsecond range and therefore droplets are extruded.
For an explanation of these g-codes, see the 'BIO X EMD Printhead' User Manual.

Well done! Many thanks for the info, this implies that they have written an extention of a known printer firmware source!

Thank you for the help!

Excellent. Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (you will have to wait 48 hours or so).

You're welcome, I find these questions fascinating! If we loo up code M750 you'll find it is a specialized command only known for RRF firmware, I imagine the M750 of these bioprinters is a further development of the G4 code. I imagine the M750 is basically a macro that: a) uses the M2065 and M2067 settings values to turn on dripping, b) wait for the specified time, and c) then turn dripping off before continuing to the next G-code instruction. Very interesting!
